# How to call a CustomValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net

There is CustomValidator for example:

```
protected void CheckAge_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
     if (//conditions)
     {
         args.IsValid = false;
         CheckAge_CustomValidator.ErrorMessage = "Error!";
     }
     else
         args.IsValid = true;
}
```

I want to call the validator in Page_Load ()
I need the result of the implementation of the validator

I need to write in the condition it
 If the Validator has started working that to execute action(`if IsValid =false`)
 Has tried so:

```
 if (CheckAge_CustomValidator.IsValid == false) //if started, and shows an error
  {
      //actions
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this on post back, add `Page.Validate("GroupName")` then check Page.IsValid.

Although, I don't quite understand why you would want to do it this way instead of validating client-side?

I would rather create a method that to handle the `//conditions` instead of a customvalidator

Answer (score 0):

On asp.net page we can call custom validator.

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" id="cusCustom" controltovalidate="txtCustom" onservervalidate="CheckAge_ServerValidate" errormessage="The text must be exactly 8 characters long!" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use either `Page.Validate` or `<customValidatorId>.Validate();`